# Which file to modify in order to permanently change values in /proc/sys

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to modify a set of values under the /proc/sys directory, but I know that each change that I made will be reset after reboot.
I want to make definitive changes to these values, so that the values will be permanently changed, even after a reboot.

Which file do I have to modify in order to achieve that?

Comment: See [procfs](http://www.olsr.org/docs/report_html/node75.html).  The files is *virtual* so some driver/kernel file is responsible for each piece of data.  Ie, it is usually a different file for each entry under *proc*.  You need to specify the file, and then read that driver.  If the value is read/write, then [`sysctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sysctl) maybe what you want.  You can add `sysctl` values to an *rc.local* file to set these values every time you boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an init.d script or so and sysctl to save and change the values also at startup.

Comment: Agree. Superuser would probably be the better place for this kind of question, but you can't make changes to /proc/sys permanent, the only thing you can do is set them in some init script every time the system reboots. Or, you compile your kernel yourself, but that's *much* more trouble than an init script.